# How to add target group from different AWS VPC and region to a AWSALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a requirement where ALB and target groups are in different VPCs as well as regions. Please advise if there is any documentation, steps/instructions or any other resource, which could help achieving this.

I think I can do this in different VPCs(same regions), but different regions, I am not sure, please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably where you want to start: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-sharing.html

Comment: You can't do this. You can only add targets from different regions, but not target groups.

Comment: @Marcin, are there any details or documentation on  why this cannot be established?

Comment: Both LBs and TGs are regional resources, as most resources in AWS. So you have to create your TGs in same region as LB, and then you can attach targets from different regions to it through VPC peering.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, I was trying to avoid this since I have a target group in a different region and didn't want to do more work. It looks like I will have to work on the approach you have suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross region VPC peering then add the instances from another region to target group